# Java Play Framework, WSRequestHolder, how to specify encoding of query parameters?

Tags: java, playframework

I am using Play 2.3 Java application, I am sending Get request to a server and I include special characters in query parameters, like Š, which is sent as %C5%A0 but server understand only Windows-1250 characters. In this case it expects %8A (see encoding https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

example:

```
wsRequestHolder.setQueryParameter("city", "Plavecký Štvrtok");
```

How can I set encoding of sending query paremeters via WSRequestHolder to something different than UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit way to define the encoding of HTTP Query parameters for WSRequestHandlers in Play.

The [RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) only defines that characters not available in the ASCII charset must be encoded in a certain way.
So its up to you to convert the String into the proper encoding that is supported by the server. Play will then escape it to be a valid URI only consisting of ASCII characters.

```
ws.RequestHolder.setQueryParameter("city", new String("Plavecký Štvrtok".getBytes(), "Cp1250")
```

See [supported encodings in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) and what their canonical names are.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it's not working, parameter is sent as

`city=Plaveck%C4%82%CB%9D%20%C4%B9%C2%A0tvrtok` (special characters were UTF-8 encoded)

it should be

`city=Plaveck%FD%20%8Atvrtok`

I think it would be beneficial for WSRequestHolder when it would be possible specify charset, like it is in Apache HttpClient https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html

`uriBuilder.setCharset(Charset.forName("Windows-1250"));`

to which I switched to overcome this obstacle